# Appending to file using savetxt

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to append array b and c to file.txt. The default behavior is to overwrite and I cant find any documentation on changing this.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1.2, 2.3, 4.5])
b = np.array([6.7, 8.9, 10.11])
c = np.array([12.13, 14.15, 16.17])

np.savetxt('file.txt', a, fmt='%1.3f', newline=", ")
```

Thanks

Comment: The documentation says `fname` can be 'filename or file handle'.  Handle means an open file.  Keep in mind that repeated writes to a `csv` can make reading that file more complicated.

Answer (score 27):

Use [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#open) with the 'append' mode, and pass the stream to the `savetxt` method:

```
with open("test.txt", "ab") as f:
    numpy.savetxt(f, a)
```

**Edit**: To add a new line, or whatever:

```
with open("test.txt", "ab") as f:
    f.write(b"\n")
    numpy.savetxt(f, a)
```

Comment: When I run this I get a TypeError for the f.write("\n") line

Comment: yeah sorry: that's because of the binary mode, the string should be added in binary format. I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 9):

You should open the file in append mode

```
import numpy as np        
f=open('file.txt','a')
a = np.array([1.2, 2.3, 4.5])
b = np.array([6.7, 8.9, 10.11])
c = np.array([12.13, 14.15, 16.17])
np.savetxt(f, a, fmt='%1.3f', newline=", ")
f.write("\n")
np.savetxt(f, b, fmt='%1.3f', newline=", ")
f.write("\n")
np.savetxt(f, c, fmt='%1.3f', newline=", ")
f.write("\n")
f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. How can I add a newline between each row?

Comment: That's not the binary keyword ('b') which was the solution, that was the 'a', for append.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, I tested it a little too fast.

Comment: II modified it to add new lines

Comment: Older numpy versions expected a `b` file because they tried to retain compatibility with PY2.  Now `savetxt` is just as happy with the text mode, 'w', 'a','wt' etc.  But your own line write has to use compatible strings.

Comment: The problem with this method is it leaves a comma at the end of every row.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler way of achieving the rows and newlines.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1.2, 2.3, 4.5])
b = np.array([6.7, 8.9, 10.11])
c = np.array([12.13, 14.15, 16.17])
      
with open('file.txt','a') as f:
    np.savetxt(f, a.reshape(1, -1), fmt='%1.3f', delimiter=",")
    np.savetxt(f, b.reshape(1, -1), fmt='%1.3f', delimiter=",")
    np.savetxt(f, c.reshape(1, -1), fmt='%1.3f', delimiter=",")
```

Contents of file.txt (assuming file.txt was empty or did not exist)

```
1.200,2.300,4.500
6.700,8.900,10.110
12.130,14.150,16.170
```

Also, note that if you don't re-open the file each time, `np.savetxt` effectively adds `b` and `c` to the existing file, so you can use the write mode from the start. Wasn't sure if this is what you wanted or to append to an already-existing file.

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    np.savetxt(f, a.reshape(1, -1), fmt='%1.3f', delimiter=",")
    np.savetxt(f, b.reshape(1, -1), fmt='%1.3f', delimiter=",")
    np.savetxt(f, c.reshape(1, -1), fmt='%1.3f', delimiter=",")
```

(Output the same as above regardless of any existing file)