# Move Python itertools combinations to file

Tags: python, python-3.5

Please help me to move Python itertools combinations to file.
I am using the below code:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
stuff = ['a',  'b' ,  'c' ,  'd']
for L in range(0, len(stuff)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(stuff, L):
        np.savetxt('x.txt', subset, fmt='%s')
        print (subset)
```

It displays full combinations in console but in file the output is just

```
a
b
c
d
```

Comment: Are you overwriting the file on each iteration?

Comment: I need all combinations in file as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54361557/appending-to-file-using-savetxt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by [Paul Rooney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1540468/paul-rooney) in his comment suggesting to use a file handle instead of a file would solve your problem:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
stuff = ['a',  'b' ,  'c' ,  'd']
with open("x.txt","wb") as fh:
    for L in range(0, len(stuff)+1):
        for subset in itertools.combinations(stuff, L): 
            np.savetxt(fh, subset, fmt="%s", header="-") 
            print (subset)
```

I added a _header: to seperate the outputs in the file:

```
# -
# -
a
# -
b
# -
c
# -
d
# -
a
b
# -
a
c
# -
a
d
# -
b
c
# -
b
d
# -
...snipp...
# -
a
b
c
d
```

To get a neater representation:

```
with open("x.txt","wb") as fh:
    for L in range(0, len(stuff)+1):
        for subset in itertools.combinations(stuff, L):
            l = list(subset)
            if l:
                format = ("%s,"*len(l)).rstrip(",")
                np.savetxt(fh, [l], fmt=format )
                print (subset)
```

to receive:

```
a
b 
c
d
a,b
a,c
a,d
b,c
b,d
c,d
a,b,c
a,b,d
a,c,d
b,c,d
a,b,c,d
```