# How to append successive calls to a single numpy file without losing precision?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, io

After some applying some procedure I am getting millions of numpy arrays (in the below case procedure converts `e` to a numpy array):

```
for e in l:
    procedure(e)
```

How can I save correctly each iteration into a single numpy file for later read it and load it?

So far I tried two options, with np.savez:

```
for i, e in enumerate(l):
    np.savez(f'/Users/user/array.npz',i=e)
```

And with pandas:

(1) For saving into a single file:

```
for e in l:
   arr = pd.DataFrame(procedure(i)).T 
   arr.to_csv('/Users/user/Downloads/arr.csv', mode='a', index=False, header=False)
```

(2) For reading:

```
arr = np.genfromtxt("/Users/user/Downloads/arr.csv", delimiter=',', dtype='float32', float_format='%.16f')
```

So far the solution that works is with pandas. However, I guess I am losing presicion in the numpy matrices. Because instead of having values like this (with the e):

`-6.82821393e-01 -2.65419781e-01`

I am getting values like this:

`-0.6828214 , -0.26541978`

However, the numpy matrices are not been saved correctly.

What is the most efficient and correct way to dump into a single file each numpy matrix after the for loop iteration?

Comment: To load a `savez`, you need to read the `savez` docs first!  `savez` is for saving multiple arrays **at once**.  It does not append successive calls to one file.  I have a feeling you are trying to write code without paying much attention to the official documentation.

Comment: @hpaulj I see, so in this case savez doesnt apply, that's why I tried with pandas but the arrays seems to be different. Any idea about how to append them in a single file after the iteration?

Comment: `csv` format is text, and is meant for 2d tables - many rows and consistent number of columns.  While you can append many times to a file, loading is difficult if the number of columns changes.   But first, tell us a bit about these arrays you are trying to save.  Do they differ in shape (and dtype)?  If they match sufficiently in shape, you might be able to concatenate them into one array, and save that.  If they differ, you need a file format that handles diverse set of objects.  `pickle` is one, though I don't recall if it can be used iteratively.

Comment: They have all the same shape. They do not differ on dtype or shape all of them have the same values. The problem right now is the lost of precision @hpaulj

Comment: You could `np.stack` them (or clusters) and use `np.save` to write the array.  `save` does not loose precision.  `savetxt` does because ir writes strings.

Comment: These are big matrices. If I `vstack` or `stack` them in a single pass my RAM will be overloaded. If I want to write to disc its because I want to release the RAM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if csv is the right format in this case, but you can specify float format to avoid precission loss.

#### Append to CSV using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.set_option('precision', 16)  # for print command

fn = 'pandasfile.csv'
arr = np.linspace(1,100,10000).reshape(5000,2)
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)

df.to_csv(fn, mode='a', index=False, header=False, float_format='%.16f', sep='\t')
```

#### Append to CSV using numpy

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(precision=16)

fn = 'numpyfile.csv'
arr = np.linspace(1,100,10000).reshape(5000,2)
print(arr)

with open(fn, "a") as f:
    np.savetxt(f, arr, fmt='%.16f', delimiter='\t')
```

I used tabulator as separator, it is more readable (some call it TSV file). You can use "," or " " instead.

#### Load CSV to numpy

```
arr2 = np.loadtxt(fn, delimiter='\t')
print(arr2)
```

#### Load CSV to pandas

```
df = pd.read_csv(fn, header=None, sep='\t', dtype='float32')
print(df)
```

Numpy version is a bit faster if it is important.

```
m@o780:~$ time python3 pdsave.py 

real    0m0,473s
user    0m0,448s
sys 0m0,102s

m@o780:~$ time python3 npsave.py 

real    0m0,199s
user    0m0,214s
sys 0m0,072s
m@o780:~$
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, however, as I mentioned in the question I am already using `float_format='%.16f'` and still losing precision. Is there any other way to not losing it? If I use `float_format='%.64f'` should that work?

Comment: I added an example, is this what you need?

Comment: So you can do `savetxt` with `a` mode in numpy? By doing that I will dump everything into a single file?

Comment: Yep, I have googled this solution and it seems to work fine. Try to run that code several times. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54361557/appending-to-file-using-savetxt

Answer (score 1):

np.savez saves an array in a zip-style format, with the default name arr_0. If you use it again, it will overwrite your current file, meaning the latest one will be there after saving. The good thing is that you can name the file in the zip, so you can use a custom name for each numpy array, or just the indices, like in the example below.

```
for i, e in enumerate(l):
 np.savez(f'/Users/user/array.npz',i=e)
```

Comment: `savez` is meant for writing a number of arrays, allowing you to retrieve them individually